# Kotlin: passing a function to a class

Tags: function, class, kotlin

I have buttons. That should reSize and move with the window. My question is, since the buttons have different positions it's quite ugly to resize them one by one by the windows specifics so I wanted to pass a function to my Buttons that calculates where to put them when the window gets resized.

I want this function to be unique so when I initialize a button I give it a lambda expression ( that uses the specifics of the window) and every time the button's updateSize method gets called it uses this lambda expression to set it's position and size.

Example code:

```
//To make it easier let's say window is a global variable

MyButton( {return Rectange(window.x, window.y, window.w, window.h) },"ButtonName")

class MyButton(updateSize(x,y,w,h) -> Rectangle,name: String )  {
  var rect: Rectangle = updateSize
  fun updateSize() {
    rect = updateSize
  }
}
```

Obviously this code does not work.

Comment: What UI framework is this for? IME you'd normally be using something like a layout manager which would take care of all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want but what about:

```
class MyButton(private val getRectangle: () -> Rectangle, name: String )  {
    var rect: Rectangle = getRectangle.invoke()
    fun updateSize() {
        rect = getRectangle.invoke()
    }
}
```

you could then do something like

```
val button1 = MyButton( { Rectangle(window.x, window.y, window.w, window.h) },"ButtonName")
```

and for another button maybe

```
val button2 = MyButton( { 
    val x = 10
    val y = someOtherFunction()
    Rectangle(x, y, window.w, window.h)
},"ButtonName")
```

Comment: But then I'd have to do this for every button i have, which defeats the porpuse. 
What i want to do exactly is to pass a function that can be called later by that class. 

So I pass fun to a Button and that button can call fun anytime it wants. and for each button this fun method does something else

Comment: @Moonlander this works like that

Comment: @Moonlander see the edit

Comment: So basically what i wanted to do was to  store a lambda expression in the class, that I can call whenever. In cpp it's possible, but i couldn't find a way in java nor kotlin to implement this. So I jsut went another way and added an offset based on the window's size. I know that what i said seems very confusing since I explained the problem very poorly, but thank you for taking the time!